# How to remove event listener inside useCallback hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a generic react hook that will add a scroll event to the element and return a boolean indicating that the user has scrolled to the top of the element.
Now, the problem is this element might not be visible right away. Hence I'm not able to use useEffect. As I understand in that situation it is [advised to use useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node)

So I did, and it works:

```
function useHasScrolled() {
  const [hasScrolled, setHasScrolled] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const setRef = useCallback((element) => {
    const handleScroll = (e) => {
      setHasScrolled(e.target.scrollTop !== 0);
    };
    if (element) {
      element.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }

    ref.current = element;
  }, []);
  return {
    hasScrolled,
    scrollingElementRef: setRef
  };
}
```

I can use my hook like this:

```
  const { hasScrolled, scrollingElementRef } = useHasScrolled();
  ....
  return <div ref={scrollingElementRef}>....
```

However, the problem is, I don't know how to remove the event listener. With the useEffect hook, it's pretty straightforward - you just return the cleanup function.

Here's the codesandbox,  if you want to check the implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-dhawan-83fdw3

Comment: You could pass the element to the hook and use `useEffect`.

Comment: Question about when exactly do you want to remove eventListener? Asking due to your ref element is removed from DOM due to conditional rendering, if you have no references to it - it will be collected by GC with all the listeners.

Comment: @SergeySosunov just like with the useEffect I was thinking about removing on unmount. Now I think about it I think you're right - since it's not a react handler it is attached to the element not a root so should be GCed when the node is removed, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expected behavior - when node is removed from DOM - event listeners will be also removed and collected by GC.

But

Codesandbox example is a bit tricky, React treats

```html
<div>Loading...</div>
```

and

```html
<div className="scrollingDiv" ref={scrollingElementRef}>
  <h1>Hello, I've finally loaded!</h1>
  <Lorem />
</div>
```

as a same div, same object, just with different props (className and children), so when div.scrollingDiv is replaced by conditional rendering to div(loading) - event listeners are still there and accumulating.

This behavior can be fixed as is by using `key`s.

```
{loading ? (
  <div key="div1">Loading...</div>
) : (
  <div key="div2" className="scrollingDiv" ref={scrollingElementRef}>
    <h1>Hello, I've finally loaded!</h1>
    <Lorem />
  </div>
)}
```

In that way event listeners will be removed as expected.

Another solution is to add 1 more useRef and useEffect to the custom hook to store and execute actual unsubscribe function:

```
function useHasScrolled() {
  const [hasScrolled, setHasScrolled] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const unsubscribeRef = useRef(null);

  const setRef = useCallback((element) => {
    const eventName = "scroll";
    const handleScroll = (e) => {
      setHasScrolled(e.target.scrollTop !== 0);
    };

    if (unsubscribeRef.current) {
      unsubscribeRef.current();
      unsubscribeRef.current = null;
    }

    if (element) {
      element.addEventListener(eventName, handleScroll);

      unsubscribeRef.current = () => {
        console.log("removeEventListener called on: ", element);
        element.removeEventListener(eventName, handleScroll);
      };
      ref.current = element;
    } else {
      unsubscribeRef.current = null;
      ref.current = null;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (unsubscribeRef.current) {
        unsubscribeRef.current();
        unsubscribeRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return {
    hasScrolled,
    scrollingElementRef: setRef
  };
}
```

That code will work without adding `key`.

Utility code for Chrome dev console to count scroll listeners:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
  .reduce(function(pre, dom){
    var clks = getEventListeners(dom).scroll;
    pre += clks ? clks.length || 0 : 0;
    return pre
  }, 0)
```

Updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-einstein-6fb1u4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you Sergey, this is a fantastic answer! Obviously the codesandbox example is contrived - I don't think the "keys" issue would appear in my real code but thank you so much for higlighting that!
Additional thanks for the helpful snippet